# How can I look inside of different chunks of strings in my Python program?

Tags: python, string, chunks

Beginner programmer here, still learning a lot. Right now I am working with a very large text file, and I want to look at the frequency of characters for different chunks of the text. For example, how often does the character "a" and "b" appear in text[0:600] verses [600:1200] versus [1200:1800], etc. Right now I only know how to print text[0:600], but I don't know how to write the syntax to tell Python to look for "a" and "b" ONLY in that chunk of the text.

I am thinking that maybe the best way to write this would be something like, "for each of these chunks I have, tell me the frequency counts of 'a' and 'b'." Does this seem doable?

Thank you so much!

Here is what I have so far, if you want to see. Its very simple:

```
f = open('text.txt')
fa = f.read()

fa = fa.lower()
corn = re.sub(r'chr', '', fa) #delete chromosome title
potato = re.sub(r'[^atcg]', '', corn) #delete all other characters

print potato[0:50]
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you have so far so we have something concrete to address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to split the text. The general case is:

```
interval = 600
chunks = [text[idx:idx+interval] for idx in range(0, len(text), interval)]
```

And to count occurrences of a sub-string (this case `a`) in a string:

```
term = 'a'
term_counts = [chunk.count(term) for chunk in chunks]
# zip them together to make it nicer (not that zip returns an iterator with python 3.4)
chunks_with_counts = zip(chunks, term_counts)
```

Example:

```
>>> text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> interval = 3
>>> chunks = [text[idx:idx+interval] for idx in range(0, len(text), interval)]
>>> chunks
['The', ' qu', 'ick', ' br', 'own', ' fo', 'x j', 'ump', 's o', 'ver', ' th', 'e
 l', 'azy', ' do', 'g']
>>> term='o'
>>> term_counts = [chunk.count(term) for chunk in chunks]
>>> term_counts
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
>>> chunks_with_counts = zip(chunks, term_counts)
>>> list(chunks_with_counts)
[('The', 0), (' qu', 0), ('ick', 0), (' br', 0), ('own', 1), (' fo', 1), ('x j',
 0), ('ump', 0), ('s o', 1), ('ver', 0), (' th', 0), ('e l', 0), ('azy', 0), ('
do', 1), ('g', 0)]
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply!!! I tried this and I get the error "Index Error: string index out of range". Any idea what this means? Would it be that when I include the command "list(chunks_with_counts)" that it is trying to list all 600 characters, and then the count? Would that make it run out of memory if I have a huge file?

Comment: You should add the stack trace to the question. It's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry about that! I am still getting used to this website! I tried it again and it worked this time so I think I had a typo. The only problem for me is that printing the chunks_with_counts is unruly, because that's 600 characters... Is there any way to print the intervals and the term_counts, similar to the chunks_with_counts? Where the result would be [('0:600', '239')], or something like this?

Comment: It's a fairly simple practice that can get you familiar with basic python tools. The information you'll need is a subset of what is used in my answer so you can try alone. If it's a problem show what you've tried in a new question and I'm sure you'll get immediate help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can position the file cursor and read from there:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as myfile:
    myfile.seek(1200)
    text = myfile.read(600)
```

This will read 600 bytes from position 1200 on. Please note that the positions might be off when there are Unicode characters in the text.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm afraid when I try this, I get the error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'". Any idea why I am seeing this or how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you are doing the `seek()` on the open file? Not a string or the already read content?

Comment: That's it! I had to cut some things out of the original file so I didn't want to use it, but it works when I use it on the actual file. Thanks! I will need to check though to see if my unwanted material is still being counted, though(?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that seems doable. You could loop through your text in chunks:

```
def compare_characters(chunk):
    # check for frequency of a and b or whatever
    pass

chunksize = 600
i = 0
while i*chunksize < len(text):
    compare_characters(text[i*chunksize:(i+1)*chunksize])
    i+=1
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and all of the edits. Every time I pushed enter, stackoverflow submitted my edit! I am having trouble implementing this. 

    def compare_characters(chunk):
        potato.count("a")
        potato.count("b")
        pass

When I run this code plus my own bits, the terminal doesn't print anything. It gets stuck in an infinite loop, maybe?